# How to apply a color filter on a png with transparency on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to paint a .png that has a transparent background:

[image]

I did:

```
              RotatedBox(
                      quarterTurns: 2,
                      child: ColorFiltered(
                        child: Image.asset('metronome_off.png', height: 25),
                        colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                            Colors.yellow, BlendMode.exclusion),
                      ))
```

And tried all possible `BlendMode.` types. In all of them the image gets painted, but also the background. How can I paint only the image?

Would it be better instead to make this trapezoid in Flutter using some paint tools? I guess it'd be too hard.

Comment: Can you upload the image the final result do you need it ?

Comment: @mam_65 here's what I get https://imgur.com/a/rDAPmtY

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try this code:

```
ColorFiltered(
colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.yellow, BlendMode.srcATop),
 child: RotatedBox(quarterTurns: 2, child: Image.asset("metronome_off.png",height: 25)),)
```